# How can we use Cloud based logistic styling for Google Maps with react-native-maps?

Tags: react-native, google-cloud-platform, google-maps-api-3, react-native-maps

I am using `react-native-maps` for my react native project. And I was wondering, Is there a way to use 'cloud-based styling', which uses map ID for styling your maps instead of JSON array.

If there is a way to use Cloud-based style as JSON, Please suggest it.

Thank you

Comment: have you figured this out? thanks.